# Django timezone fields don't accept all pytz timezones

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz, django-timezone

[Django timezone fields](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field) are built upon [pytz timezones](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), but some of the timezones of the latter are not valid for the fields. With a model like

```
from django.db import models
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField

class TestModel(models.Model):
    timezone_field = TimeZoneField(default='UTC')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    self.full_clean()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I run (in a shell)

```
import pytz
from models import TestModel

model = TestModel.objects.get(id=1)

for zone in pytz.all_timezones:
    model.timezone = zone
    model.save()
```

I get

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'timezone': ["Value <DstTzInfo 'Africa/Asmera' LMT+2:27:00 STD> is not a valid choice."]}
```

So it fails first on `'Africa/Asmera'` (it fails on others too, e.g. `'GMT+0'`).

Any idea of how to resolve this inconsistency? At the moment the user can select a timezone on the frontend that will give a backend error (the frontend is built in React and gets the timezones from [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/))

Comment: The choices are only the `common_timezones`, not `all_timezones`.

Comment: Aha.. Any idea how to get `common_timezones` into javascript? (Apart from printing them and saving in a file that is)? Also, if you write it as an answer I'll accept

Comment: How do you now obtain the timezones in JavaScript? The package has support for form fields, and those are - as far as I know - `common_timezones` as well.

Comment: I get them from moment timezone: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: well the package has functionality for a form field. So you can use the attached formfield.

Comment: you can use django-timezone-field==4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Willem mentioned in V1.2 of Django Timezone Fields, they changed the field's default choices from `all_timezones` to `common_timezones`. You can revert this change by explicitly setting the `choices` attribute in the field definition.

https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field

> 1.2 (2015-02-05) For form field, changed default list of accepted timezones from pytz.all_timezones to pytz.common_timezones, to match
>   DB field behavior.
>   1.1 (2014-10-05) Django 1.7 compatibility Added support for formating choices kwarg as [[, ], ...], in addition to previous format
>   of [[, ], ...]. Changed default list of accepted
>   timezones from pytz.all_timezones to pytz.common_timezones. If you
>   have timezones in your DB that are in pytz.all_timezones but not in
>   pytz.common_timezones, this is a backward-incompatible change. Old
>   behavior can be restored by specifying choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in
>   pytz.all_timezones] in your model definition.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    timezone_field = TimeZoneField(default='UTC', choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.all_timezones])
```

***There is a disclaimer about this being a backwards incompatible change; so I urge you to look into this further***